# What is the Max results that can be fetched for DocuSign Envelopes : listStatusChanges API

Tags: docusignapi

What is the Max results that can be fetched for Docusign Envelopes : listStatusChanges API
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/

The max count value is not specified in the documentation.
Also would like to know the default result size

Answer (score 0):

There's no defined maximum and it can change in different conditions. You get the information about the size in the first few lines of JSON. If it's too many envelopes for one call - you get a URI to make a call for the next set and you know how many in each request:

```
"resultSetSize": "575",
  "startPosition": "0",
  "endPosition": "201",
  "totalSetSize": "575",
  "nextUri": "URI to make next call",
  "previousUri": "URI for previous call",
```